# How to add a shift key to an iOS 8 Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, shift, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

Right now I have created a basic prototype custom keyboard, however, I do not know how to make a shift key that would capitalize the letters. Right now the letters are all lowercase. Also I wrote this in Objective-C not Swift, but a swift based solution is welcome as well! :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a key that toggles between whatever images you are using for it. When the key is toggled to shifted, store that in a boolean property.

Then, use this code for each key press:

```
- (NSString *)stringForAKeyPress:(id)sender {
   if (self.shifted) {
       return @"A";
   } else {
       return @"a";
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay because what I had done was create button in the .xib file and put them into the order of a QWERTY keyboard then give them their corresponding letter. Then i put all the characters into this array: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *keysArray;
After that in the ViewController.m I added this code so that when the keys are pressed theyll input their character title: - (void)pressKey:(UIButton *)key{
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[key currentTitle]];
}

Comment: How would I use the image method you mentioned? I remember seeing it before but I just don't know how'd I would go about it. Thank you.

Comment: Why not return [@"a" uppercaseString];

Comment: Can you put a solution in swift as well please?

Comment: @crost Someone else would be welcome to write an additional answer! I haven't coded in like six years haha.